# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Batch without an ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Basically I have a dropdown that's meant to launch a partial by calling a method in the controller. The partial is shown below:

```
<%= form_for :exam_report, :url=>{:action=>'generated_report'} do |z| %>

<%= select_tag :exam_report_batch, 
options_for_select(
Batch.find(:all,:select=>"name,id").collect{|c| [c.name,c.id]}),
:data => { :remote => true, :url => url_for(:controller => "exam", 
                                 :action => "list_exam_types",
                                 :prompt =>"Select a batch")} %>


 <div id="exam-group-select">
 <%= select :exam_report, :exam_group_id, @exam_groups.map{|exam| [exam.name,exam.id]},:prompt=> "#{t('select_exam_group')}" %>
</div>

 <%= z.submit "View", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

 <% end %>
```

The "list_exam_types" method in the Exam controller is shown below:

```
def list_exam_types
batch = Batch.find(params[:batch_id])
@exam_groups = ExamGroup.find_all_by_batch_id(batch.id)
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js   
end
end
```

So when I select a batch from the dropdown, I get the following error: **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Batch without an ID):
  app/controllers/exam_controller.rb:224:in `list_exam_types'**

My routes are shown below:

```
resources :batches do
resources :exam_groups
resources :additional_exam_groups
resources :elective_groups
end 

resources :exam_groups do
resources :exams do
  member do
    post :save_scores
  end
end
end
```

I think I have down my routes well so I don't know why params[:batch_id] is empty. Your help will be greatly appreciated, thanx!

Comment: Resource routes usually require an `id`, not a `<name>_id`. If you examine the params in the `list_exam_types` (with debugger), do you see a `batch_id`? Or, just try: `batch = Batch.find(params[:id])` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: well your suggestion doesn't work as the same error is still being raised.am also puzzled that 'list_exam_types' has no 'batch_id' associated with it

Comment: Did you try a breakpoint in the list_exam_types method to see what params were being passed?

Comment: yep, and i've realized that it's not being populated. so am wondering how to do it,,